# The largest number of people have applied this year

Tags: grammatical-number

### For those who are familiar with CGEL:

If you're not familiar with CGEL and find CGEL's explanation too technical, please skip the CGEL part and start reading the question in the second part:

*The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (Page 350) says:

> *Number* and *couple* permit only plural obliques, partitive or non-partitive: *a number of the protesters*/**money*, *a couple of days*/**hope*. Both occur in singular form with an obligatory determiner (usually *a*, but others are possible as shown in [58]), and in addition *number* can occur in the plural, and take a limited range of adjectival modifiers:
>
> [58] i We found [huge *numbers* of ants] swarming all over the place.
>
> ii If [this *number* of people] come next time we’ll bring in professional caterers.
>
> iii [Any *number* of people] could have done a better job than that.
>
> iv [The *couple* of mistakes she had made] were easily corrected.
>
> v [An unusually large *number* of people] have applied this year.
>
> vi [How large a *number* of students] have enrolled, did you say?
>
> **The definite article *the* does not occur with *number* in the sense we are concerned with here.** In the number-transparent sense it indicates an imprecise number, but elsewhere it indicates a precise number, and in that case it can take *the*, as in *The number of protesters arrested has not been revealed*, where the subject NP is singular by virtue of having singular non-transparent *number* as head.
>
> (Boldface mine.)

In the emboldened statement, **the sense we are concerned with here** refers to "the number-transparent sense" (mentioned in the following sentence), by which CGEL means that the number of the whole NP depends on the oblique.

See these examples:

> [*A lot of work*] *was done.*
>
> [*A lot of errors*] *were made.*

Here, the noun *lot* in the NP *a lot of work*/*errors*  is "number-transparent" in that it allows the number of the oblique *work*/*errors* to percolate up to determine the number of the whole NP *a lot of work*/*errors*.

With that in mind, take a look at a variant of [58v]:

> (1) [The largest *number* of people] **have** applied this year.

Here, I think *have*, but not *has*, is correct, which means that the number of the NP in the bracket depends on the oblique *people*, and that the noun *number* here is number-transparent.

Is (1) a counterexample of the emboldened statement of CGEL?

---

### For those who are not familiar with CGEL:

Here's a usage note from [Oxford Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/number):

> The construction ***the number of* + plural noun** is used with a singular verb (as in *the number of people affected remains small*). Thus it is the noun *number* rather than the noun *people* that is taken to agree with the verb (and is therefore functioning as the head noun).
>
> By contrast, the apparently similar construction ***a number of* + plural noun** is used with a plural verb (as in *a number of people remain to be contacted*). In this case, it is the noun *people* that acts as the head noun and with which the verb agrees. In the latter case, *a number of* works as if it were a single word, such as *some* or *several*.

But in (1), it is the noun *people* that acts as the head noun and with which the verb agrees, but you have *the* before *number*.

> (1) [The largest *number* of people] **have** applied this year.

Is (1) a counterexample of the Oxford usage note?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108095/discussion-on-question-by-jk2-the-largest-number-of-people-have-applied-this-yea).

Answer (score 5):

It seems a number-transparent use of *number* can, in fact, take *the* when separated from it by some other word:

> ii If [the **same / expected** number of people] come next time we’ll bring in
>   professional caterers.
>
> iii [Only the **tiniest / stated** number of people] have done a better job than
>   that.
>
> iv [The **other / record** number of mistakes she had made] were easily
>   corrected.
>
> v [The **average / required / perfect** number of people] have applied this year.

So, the ban on *the* for the number transparent use seems intended for the case in which *the* is the only pre-head element in the NP, where there's nothing separating *the* from *number*. Of course, it would be possible to write:

> If [**the number** of people **expected**] come next time, we'll bring in
>   professional caterers.
>
> Only [**the number** of people **stated**] have done a better job than that.
>
> [**The number** of people **required**] have applied this year.

Thus it seems that as long as *number* is modified so that we can pick out a particular number, number-transparent *number* can take *the*.

Comment: If this is the case, I think you've spotted something that neither CGEL nor traditional grammar was able to figure out. Is there any source for your answer? Or is this something you have originally come up with?

Comment: @JK2 It's something I came up with while trying to figure out why your example (1) worked.

Comment: Great job! I'll have to wait for your answer to go through some vetting process by other reviewers, but unless your theory is disproved, I'll probably be awarding the bounty. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> [The largest number of people] have applied this year.

I suspect the superlative *largest* is queering the deal here.

> Last year's 50,000 applicants was well above average. However, the
>   largest number of people ever [have/has] applied this year.

To my ear, either *have* or *has* is possible, but I prefer *has*, probably because of the *was* in the first sentence. This is a matter of notional agreement working with a different sense of number than CGEL's transparent sense.

> All of last year's 50,000 applicants were drug tested. However, the largest
>   number of people ever [have/has] applied this year, causing this policy to be reviewed.

Notional agreement may be more acceptable here due to the parallel structure.

In terms of transparency, the superlative or comparative has to match the sense of what it is being compared to. I score that as non-transparent with respect to the PP.

Comment: Are you sure that _Last year's 50,000 applicants was well above average_ is natural? I don't think that's a terribly natural thing to say. I'd say instead: _The number of last year's applicants, which was 50,000, was well above average._ But I could be wrong, so I'd like you to present me with some attested examples treating something like _50,000 applicants_ as singular using the concept of "notional agreement". AFAIK, notional agreement is not a license to treat _50,000 applicants_ as singular, nor is the application of "notional agreement" influenced by a prior sentence.

Comment: @JK2: With "last year's 50,000 applicants," the *applicants* weren't above average; it's the number *50,000* that was above average. So you have to use the singular (assuming you don't rewrite the sentence, which is clearly the best thing to do).

Comment: @JK2 I was actually thinking that *have* would be the notional agreement, with *has* being the default. They way I wrote it muddled that idea. The *issue* is one of notional agreement. In my first example, my ear says *probably not* to notional agreement, In the second, it says yes. And yes, the sentences were contrived to facilitate the OP's somewhat quirky example.

Comment: @PeterShor I would never say _Last year's 50,000 applicants **were** well above average._ But I find _Last year's 50,000 applicants **was** well above average_ sloppy. Do you find the latter natural? Also, I've added a comment to one of your past answers that is related to this question. Please check that out.

Comment: @PhilSweet I see where you're coming from. Thanks for clearing that up. But I still can't wrap my head around the notional agreement being influenced by a separate, prior sentence.