# "There exists a number of.." vs. "There exist a number of.."

Tags: grammar

Which of the following statements is correct?

"While there **exist** a number of problem-specific techniques in the literature, little progress has been made towards a generic approach."

Or,

"While there **exists** a number of problem-specific techniques in the literature, little progress has been made towards a generic approach."

I understand that, in a normal context, the former is used when the subject is plural and the latter is used when it is singular. In this case though, it is not immediately clear which element should be considered the subject of the sentence: are we talking about the group of techniques that **exist**; or, are we talking about the *number itself* that **exists**?

My intuition says that it should be the former, as the techniques themselves are the important information, and the number is unspecified - we could, for example, substitute the word "several" for "a number" and it would unambiguously be exist. However, I just received feedback from a reviewer about a conference paper I submitted, which told me to change exist to exists.

I suppose, either way, I should probably just change it to "several" and remove the ambiguity altogether, but I am curious to know which way is the most correct, for my own edification.

Comment: Personally I disagree with the reviewer since I see the phrase "a number of" as being an inexact equivalent of a careful count of the number of techniques so that you could replace "a number of" with "forty-two" and the sentence structure would be the same. However it is a matter of opinion which is correct and, probably, either is acceptable. I don't really think that you will get a definitive answer to this question.

Comment: Related: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/533372/the-largest-number-of-people-have-applied-this-year

Comment: You wouldn't say *There is a number of techniques...*, would you? Or *A number of pieces is missing*? We use notional agreement — plural here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use "a number of Plurals" in the Plural Sense , to indicate two or more (generally a lot more) of Items.
Hence "...  there **exist** a number of Problem-Specific techniques in the literature ..." is valid.

We use "the number of Plurals" in the Singular Sense to indicate some Single Number (known or unknown) of the Items.

Hence , "The number of books in this library **is** 10,549 to be Exact" or "Estimate the number of Cars in this Area" will be valid , where there will be some Specific numbers.

There **are** a number of online Articles about this topic. The number of Articles I have included in my list **is** 4 :

https://www.editage.com/insights/scientific-writing-a-number-of-and-the-number-of
https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/numbers/the-number-vs-a-number/
https://www.dominatethegmat.com/2012/01/a-number-vs-the-number-gmat-sentence-correction/
https://www.grammar-monster.com/lessons/singular_plural_number.htm

**My general Observations or Thoughts :**

There are Cases where we use "a number" (not "a number of Plurals") to indicate a general Singular Number. Eg "Write a number between 1 and 100"

There are Cases where we use "the number" (not "the number of Plurals") to indicate a Specific Singular Number. Eg "The number you wrote was 44"

We use "a number of Singular" when talking about some Singular Entity having many numbers & we want 1 out of those Numbers. Eg "Give me a [Contact] number of the School"

We can also use "the number of Singular" when talking about some Singular Entity having a Single number. Eg "Give me the Number of your Bank Account"

**My Observations or Thoughts on the Specific Case :**

Warning : This Section can be ignored !

I did not want to include this Part earlier , because I thought it is unnecessary & distracting & rambling in nature , but I am including it after seeing the comments by user "BoldBen" & user "Henry" , who have Ideas related to this Part.

The reviewer is wrong , but you have to adjust to that reviewer to get the Article through. Either change it to the wrong but acceptable version , or avoid it by rephrasing entirely.

When looking to why the reviewer is wrong , we have two Points :

(1) The Earlier Part shows the standard usage of the Singularity or Plurality of "number of" , with relevant online Articles. We can argue with the reviewer with that , though it will be futile.

(2) Let us assume , the reviewer is right : we have to use Singular Sense with "While there exists a number of problem-specific techniques in the literature, little progress has been made towards a generic approach."

Consider Statements like "While (or Even though) X is true , Y is not true"

Generally , when X is true , we expect Y to be true. When that is not the Case , we may say "Even though (or While) X is true , Y is not true" , which makes sense to show the astonishment.

Eg X="She is a weight lifter" , Y="She is looking strong"
"While she is a weight lifter , she is not looking too strong" (astonishment)

In the given Statement , we have X = "there Exists a number (of techniques)" & Y = "Progress has been made towards a generic approach"
"While there Exists a number (of techniques) , no Progress has been made towards a generic approach"
It is a meaningless Statement. The number of techniques always Exists (might be 0 , 1 , 10 , 100 , 1000) & hence there can be no astonishment.

Instead , in the given Statement , we can have X = "there are a lot (or lots) of techniques" & Y = "Progress has been made towards a generic approach"
"While there are a lot (or lots) of techniques , no Progress has been made towards a generic approach"
It is a meaningful Statement. The number of techniques is large & no Progress has been made , hence there is astonishment.

Hence "Exist a number of techniques" means "Exist a lot (or lots) of techniques" in the Plural Sense.

Enough rambling !

Comment: 1 is a number, so if you have done something once then you can say you have done it a number of times.  For over a millennium 0 has been treated as a number,  so if you have never done something then you can say ... . Note that zero is implicitly plural as in "zero times" in contrast to "one time".